# Fechar um Collapse ao abrir outro usando AngularJS UI

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Eu tenho um collapse e outro logo do lado, eu queria que ao clicar em um, fechar o outro caso estivesse aberto.

Meu código html:

```js
angular.module("seuCondominio", ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module("seuCondominio").controller("seuCondominioCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = true;
  $scope.isCollapsededit = true;
  $scope.tarefas = [{
    id: 0,
    nome: "Lavar alguma coisa",
    inicio: "10/10/10",
    conclusao: "11/10/10",
    custo: "1000",
    status: {
      nome: "Concluído"
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="seuCondominio">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-controller="seuCondominioCtrl">

  <div id="editar">
    <button id="lapis" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsededit = !isCollapsededit">Simbolo</span>
    </button>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>{{' ' + tarefas[0].nome}}</button>
    <div collapse="isCollapsededit" style="position:relative">
      Conteudo 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div collapse="isCollapsed" style="position:relative">
    Conteudo 2
  </div>
  </div>

</html>
</body>
```

Então, queria que, de algum jeito, quando clicasse em um, o outro fechasse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que posso usar mais de um comando no ng-click usando ";", assim coloquei

```
ng-click="acc1 = !acc1; acc2 = true
```

e

```
ng-click="acc2 = acc2; acc1 = true
```

nos buttons e funcionou

valeu grl ^^